# Spring MVC Notification System

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, notifications, push-notification

I want to develop a notification system using springMVC, I want to notify the authenticated user if  someone else connected in an other browser performed a specific action(press button,etc...) and vise versa such as facebook notification system.

I don't know the notification concepts that i have to use to achieve that(polling, ...).
What are the recommended tools or libraries to use them?
if there is links or tutorials that help me to achieve this work ?

thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If only the server sends data to the client, I think that the Sse Emitters are a good choice.

Take a look on:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-sse-streams